# VBA convert date to a number based on text box input

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a userform I am making. An input box will open and the user will enter a month. Then The userform will open, inputting that month into textbox3. I want text box 1 to be 1&the number form of that month. I have tried several types of code but i am fairly new to vba.

Help would be appreciated.
Here is the code i have tried.

```
TextBox1=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1"&TextBox2.value))
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Try as `TextBox1=Month(DateValue(TextBox2.value & "/01/2017"))`. VBA is very EN-US-centric and VBA dates should be MDY unless specifically accounted to a different regional setting. BTW, if you are putting the month number into TextBox2, why are you retrieving the same (calculated) month number into TextBox1?

Comment: I want the month (December) to appear In Text Box 2. In Text Box1 i want the number of the month to appear and the number 1 in front of it. Ex TextBox1 112 and TextBox2 December

Answer (score 2):

With `December` in TextBox2, use,

```
 TextBox1 = "1" & Month(DateValue("1-" & TextBox2.value))
```

TBH, I really wouldn't trust my users to spell the month name correctly but have them select from a list instead.

Comment: So I added a combo Box, added each month in, when i add your line of code in, I get an error object 13 when opening the userform. I put your line of code in the userform_initialize

Comment: I figured it. i added your code to initialize, should have put it in the combobox1_Change()Thank you

Comment: So most of the code works...When i select October, November, or December, it doesnt change...It should input 110, 111, and 112 respectively into TextBox1

Comment: It seems to be choking on double-digit month numbers (October is the first with `10`). Do you want March to be `13` or `103`? Is TextBox1 wide enough to show three digits? Is TextBox1's MaxLength property set at 2?